# How to get rid of unwanted tabs in text on tkinter with python line continuation

Tags: python, tkinter, line-continuation

I have the following code and when it shows in my GUI it includes the indentations for the code structure. How can i get rid of these?

```
        warningLbl = tkinter.Label(window, text = '!!This Tool Will not work with\
        IVER builds!!', font="16", fg="red")
```

The text for the label prints like
[image]

Comment: Change to `... '!!This Tool Will not work with'\
        'IVER builds!!' ...`

Comment: Just ends the first line as `... work with '` and starts the second line as `'IVER ...`.

Comment: Thank you!
I had done that, but I wasn't sure if that is "per the style guides"?